# Error on running angular 2 app npm start

Tags: angular, npm, node-modules

---

> This is the error while compiling the application.  my @angular/cli:
>   1.2.4 version
>
> ---
>
> @angular/cli: 1.2.4
>   node: 8.11.1
>   os: win32 x64
>   @angular/animations: 4.3.6
>   @angular/common: 4.3.6
>   @angular/compiler: 4.3.6
>   @angular/core: 4.3.6
>   @angular/forms: 4.3.6
>   @angular/http: 4.3.6
>   @angular/platform-browser: 4.3.6
>   @angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.3.6
>   @angular/router: 4.3.6
>   @angular/compiler-cli: 4.3.6
>   @angular/cli: 1.2.4
>   @angular/language-service: 4.3.6

```
This is the error while compiling the application.  



ERROR in ./~/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"importLoaders":1}!./~/postcss-loader?{"ident":"postcss"}!./src/styles.css
Module build failed: BrowserslistError: Unknown browser query `dead`
    at error (C:\Github project\angForm\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:37:11)
    at C:\Github project\angForm\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:222:9
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at browserslist (C:\Github project\angForm\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:196:13)
    at Browsers.parse (C:\Github project\angForm\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\browsers.js:44:14)
    at new Browsers (C:\Github project\angForm\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\browsers.js:39:28)
    at loadPrefixes (C:\Github project\angForm\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\autoprefixer.js:56:18)
    at plugin (C:\Github project\angForm\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\autoprefixer.js:62:18)
    at LazyResult.run (C:\Github project\angForm\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:274:20)
    at LazyResult.asyncTick (C:\Github project\angForm\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:189:32)
    at LazyResult.asyncTick (C:\Github project\angForm\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:201:22)
    at processing.Promise.then._this2.processed (C:\Github project\angForm\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:228:20)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at LazyResult.async (C:\Github project\angForm\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:225:27)
    at LazyResult.then (C:\Github project\angForm\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:131:21)
    at C:\Github project\angForm\node_modules\postcss-loader\index.js:129:55
 @ ./src/styles.css 4:14-134
 @ multi ./src/styles.css

ERROR in ./src/app/app.component.css
Module build failed: BrowserslistError: Unknown browser query `dead`
    at error (C:\Github project\angForm\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:37:11)
    at C:\Github project\angForm\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:222:9
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at browserslist (C:\Github project\angForm\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:196:13)
    at Browsers.parse (C:\Github project\angForm\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\browsers.js:44:14)
    at new Browsers (C:\Github project\angForm\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\browsers.js:39:28)
    at loadPrefixes (C:\Github project\angForm\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\autoprefixer.js:56:18)
    at plugin (C:\Github project\angForm\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\autoprefixer.js:62:18)
    at LazyResult.run (C:\Github project\angForm\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:274:20)
    at LazyResult.asyncTick (C:\Github project\angForm\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:189:32)
    at LazyResult.asyncTick (C:\Github project\angForm\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:201:22)
    at processing.Promise.then._this2.processed (C:\Github project\angForm\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:228:20)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at LazyResult.async (C:\Github project\angForm\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:225:27)
    at LazyResult.then (C:\Github project\angForm\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:131:21)
    at C:\Github project\angForm\node_modules\postcss-loader\index.js:129:55
 @ ./src/app/app.component.ts 18:17-47
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200 ./src/main.ts
```

Answer (score 8):

I have upgraded Angular Cli to version 6 and generated a new project. Then tried to use an angular 5 template within this project folder and got the same error as I ran ng serve --open. Deleting the file "browserslist" (it is under the src/) solved my problem.